# c programming using a static variable and then pointing to it ? possible?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-address, static-variables

In c when creating and returning the address in a static variable inside a function would it be the same as
initializing a simple

`int sNum2 = 0 ; int * temp = &sNum2;`

? static will basically have it's own allocated size in the memory right?

and i could just point to it from the staticNum function from now?

Maybe is not a good practice but is it ok to use?

```
 int * staticNum(){
  int static sNum=0;
  int * temp=&sNum;
  sNum++;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: A `static` variable declared inside a function essentially is a global variable, that's visible only from inside the function it's been declared in. So there's only one instance of this variable.

Comment: A problem with this is a routine that returns a static buffer can only be used once until the caller no longer needs its buffer. Calling it a second time overwrites the previous data.

Comment: To add to @EricPostpischil comment, be very careful to document if your function is unsafe to call from multiple threads which, if it uses statics, is more likely than not:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid code.

A `static` variable, whether declared at file scope or inside of a function, has full program lifetime.  That means its address will always be valid and can be safely dereferenced at any point in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's ok to use. A pointer to a static variable, is just like any other pointer. Just pointing to the place in the data segment where the static variable is stored.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum for pointing that out.

Comment: @kaylum: More properly, “heap” is a type of data structure: [a tree that satisfies the heap property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). Dynamically allocated memory is not necessarily a heap, nor vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The returned pointer from the function

```
  int * staticNum(){
  int static sNum=0;
  int * temp=&sNum;
  sNum++;
  return temp;
}
```

will be valid because the static variable `sNum` will be alive after exiting the function.